# Google Docs: Using ImportHtml with an URL that contains commas and single quotes

Tags: google-docs

I've constructed a google docs spreadsheet that fetches card prices (from a collectible card game) from a website using importhtml.

Here's an example that works:

URL: https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Magic+Origins/Abbot+of+Keral+Keep

Function: =importhtml(B4;"table";2) where B4 is the cell with the above URL.

This will return a table with pricing information for the named card "Abbot of Keral Keep", which belongs to a set of cards named "Magic Origins". So far so good. Where I run into problems is when the card name contains either a comma or a single quote. In that case the URL for a card named "Chandra, Fire of Kaladesh / Chandra, Roaring Flame" looks like this:

URL: https://www.magiccardmarket.eu/Products/Singles/Magic+Origins/Chandra%2C+Fire+of+Kaladesh+%2F+Chandra%2C+Roaring+Flame

The importhtml function can't retrieve data from that URL (and it's not because of the %2F from the "/", since this is not a problem for cards that don't contain commas or single quotes).

Can any1 help me solve this? Tyvm.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.